# Spring injected references in Kotlin

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

In Kotlin, a variable must be initialized at declaration time, and cannot be `null` unless it has `?` appended to the type name. So a bean reference intended to be injected by Spring would have to be declared as:

```
@AutoWired
var someService: SomeService? = null
```

The nuisance is obviously that from here on everywhere `someService` is used, some kind of null-safety logic has to be specified, be it `?:` or a straight-up null check.

Of course we can do:

```
@AutoWired
var someService = new SomeService()
```

But that's not always possible, and the throwaway instance is just confusing.

My question is, is there anyway to tell Kotlin that this variable will be initialized and actually not be `null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options.

**1) use constructor injection**

Constructor injection is in my opinion the best way because it clearly declares that the dependencies must be set to construct the object.

**2) declare your field as lateinit**

Read more on tht topic in the doc:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html

> Late-Initialized Properties
>
> Normally, properties declared as having a non-null type must be
>   initialized in the constructor. However, fairly often this is not
>   convenient. For example, properties can be initialized through
>   dependency injection, or in the setup method of a unit test. In this
>   case, you cannot supply a non-null initializer in the constructor, but
>   you still want to avoid null checks when referencing the property
>   inside the body of a class.

```
public class MyTest {
    lateinit var subject: TestSubject

    @SetUp fun setup() {
        subject = TestSubject()
    }

    @Test fun test() {
        subject.method()  // dereference directly
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Spring project official recommendation is to use constructor injection. 
In Kotlin it will look something like this:

```
@Service
class GobblinMetricsConsumer(
    private val graphiteClient: GraphiteClient,
    private val parserService: JsonParserService,
    private val kafkaConfigurationProperties: KafkaConfigurationProperties
) {
  // code will go here
}
```